# Throwing error with Python BackSlash

Tags: python, backslash

Intenstion is to remove all *.properties file, this code is reused for other purpose also, so relative path and join is used.
Here am unable to run

```
DestDirName ="..\\Folder\\name\\present\\here\\"
Destbase_filename='*'
filename_suffix = '.properties'
Destfn = os.path.join(DestDirName, Destbase_filename + filename_suffix)
os.remove(Destfn)
```

It is throwing below error

> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:

Please suggest

Comment: Are you sure that `remove` can operate on wildcards like "*"? I thought you had to give it a literal name.

Answer (score 1):

`os.remove` can only remove one file at a time. You need to remove the files individually. Use `glob.glob`.

```
    import glob
    files = glob.glob(Destfn)
    for file in files:
         os.remove(file)
```